# Why cant I add a foreign key here, when the table and the column exists and are same type?

Tags: mysql

First table

```
CREATE TABLE `payments` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `payment_status_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Second Table
So i am trying to add a foreign key but getting an error: `ER_CANNOT_ADD_FOREIGN: Cannot add foreign key constraint`
Now I cant figure out why this error is happening. The column types are the same? The key is even being added seperate later on after both tables are being created. What am i missing here?

```
CREATE TABLE `payment_statuses` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` char(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Adding FK:

```
alter table payments add constraint `payments_payment_status_id_foreign` foreign key (`payment_status_id`) references `id` (`payment_statuses`);
```

Comment: The other table is called `payment_statuses`, not `id`. You have to swap the arguments.

Comment: @Progman F, how i missed that i have no idea. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: You have to admit though, that the error message is about as lame as an error message can get.  It is basically saying "Can't do that. Go figure why. Sucker."

Comment: For mysql version 8.0.22 the error message was "ERROR 1824 (HY000): Failed to open the referenced table 'id'".